How to query tx by calldata suffix?
I'm building application with frog
within frog, we can add datasuffix on tx calldata like below
in my case, it's fc000023c0
and I want to query all tx made from my application.
anyone know good way to get by these datasuffix, or any other way to get all tx?
refs
https://opensea.notion.site/Seaport-Order-Attributions-ec2d69bf455041a5baa490941aad307f
https://warpcast.notion.site/Frame-Transactions-Public-9d9f9f4f527249519a41bd8d16165f73#c1c3182208ce4ae4a7ffa72129b9795a
